# even if we have enough RAM space, why OS will use SWAP memory?

Tags: linux, memory, swap

[image]

from the above pic, you can see we have 3191 RAM free, but at the same swap is also using about 661 bytes. why it is occurring ? can any give a glance regarding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most likely reason on a linux box, your `swappiness` is set to a non-zero number. See [This Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness) and the accepted answer for the direct reason why you have free memory and swap in use. That said, if you're asking this question, it's probably best to leave the `swappiness` at the default value.

Other possible reason: That 3GB of memory was in use and only recently freed up. The system will not waste time loading data out of swap and into memory until it knows that it actually needs it (i.e., page faults)

General explination, as applies to most major modern operating systems:

You can never have enough memory (Unless you have more RAM than you do harddisk space). RAM isn't just for memory that applications need to run ("Active" memory). It is also used heavily for memory-mapping files and caching data.

The entire purpose of a memory manager is to look at the system and say "Alright, I've got 8GB of memory, and I have `$diskSize+$applicationMemory` data to fit into it. What's most important?" It will try to move the least important data to the disk, and the most important data into memory.

This works great for mapped files and cached files. They already exist on disk (as files), so if they become "unimportant", then the system can just drop them from memory. If they become important again, it can load them from the original file. Application memory is different; It doesn't normally exist on the disk, so the system has to save unimportant application memory to swap.

The problem is that saving unimportant application memory to disk is just as slow as loading important files from disk; To help minimize the amount of time spent waiting to unload unimportant application memory, the system will preemptively "guess" which pieces of memory are unimportant, and copy those to swap early. This allows it to just drop the application memory from RAM if something more important comes along.

---

If you're wondering how something can possibly be more important than active application memory, consider a background process that checks for updates once every 24 hours. 99.9% of the time, this program is doing nothing but sleeping. The system will identify applications like this, and push them out to swap so that there is more room for cached files (like logs or configuration files, which may be written to or read from many times a second).

---

**TL;DR**: You don't have enough RAM (RAM < Disk Size + Application Memory). Free RAM is a temporarily illusion that will be corrected as you use the system. Swap is in use because the system has identified low-priority application memory and already pushed *a copy of it* to disk so that it can very quickly make room for higher priority things if it needs to.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: They're copies of information that was in memory at one time (and probably still has) that hasn't been accessed or modified in a long time.

When your system starts up, a lot of services start running. These services allocate memory, read in their configuration, and so on. They dirty some memory pages. Many of these services will never run again for the entire time your system is running because you don't use them. But the operating system can't discard the memory pages they modified. Some of them might be important.

Now, your system could write these pages to swap later, when it's under memory pressure and has to do some paging. But that would be the worst time to do extra I/O, because at that time, I/O is limiting your system's performance.

So instead, it writes those pages to swap right now, when it has plenty of spare I/O bandwidth. That way, if it later comes under memory pressure, it can safely discard them without additional I/O because it can read them back from swap.

If it ultimately does discard those pages, there's another benefit. The system now has more RAM it can use as a disk cache.